# Swapping text of parent and child elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, mouseevent, addeventlistener

I have the following elements:

```
<div contenteditable="true" id="write">
  <div class="tooltip">
    <span>test</span>&nbsp; <!--text to be written in text area-->
    <span class="tooltiptext"> <!--holds words to be displayed on hover-->
      <span class="popUpWord">hello</span>
      <br>
      <span class="popUpWord">dog</span>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="tooltip">
  <span>test</span>&nbsp;
  <span class="tooltiptext">
    <span class="popUpWord">hello</span>
    <br>
    <span class="popUpWord">test</span>
  </span> 
  </div>
</div>
```

These basically show a pop-up similar to the following - http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_tooltip

On hover event of elements having the '.tooltop' class (words to be displayed inside the pop-up area), I would like to swap the word which is hovered in the pop-up area, with the word displayed in the text area after a couple of seconds.

I did the following function:

```
//--choosing word from pop-up list--//

$(document).on("mouseover", ".popUpWord", function(e)
{
if(!timeoutId)
{
    timeoutId=window.setTimeout(function()
    {
        timeoutId=null;
        e.currentTarget.innerHTML = e.fromElement.parentElement.parentElement.childNodes[0].childNodes[0].innerText;
        /*not working*/  e.fromElement.parentElement.parentElement.childNodes[0].childNodes[0].innerHTML = e.currentTarget.innerHTML; //Although the elements I want to swap are referred to correctly,the element's text is not changing. (Tried using innerText)  
    },1500);
}
}).on('mouseout', '.popUpWord', function(e)
{
if(timeoutId)
{
    window.clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    timeoutId=null;
}
});
```

However, in the line marked `not working` - the element's text is not changing. And it is being referred to correctly.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Its because you are assigning the value of tooltip to the text element and re-assigning it to the tooltip.

Try this:

```
timeoutId=null;
var text = e.currentTarget.innerHTML;
e.currentTarget.innerHTML = e.fromElement.parentElement.parentElement.childNodes[0].childNodes[0].innerText;
e.fromElement.parentElement.parentElement.childNodes[0].childNodes[0].innerHTML = text;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to locate the source and destination elements in a way that can only lead to brittleness and errors. Give elements you know you want to work with `id`s and reference them that way.

Try this out. Hover over "helo".

```js
var orig = $("orig");
var hold = $("hold");
var timeoutId = null;

$(".popUpWord").on("mouseover", function(e){
  if(!timeoutId) {
    timeoutId = setTimeout(function() {
      e.target.innerHTML = original.textContent;
      original.innerHTML = e.target.innerHTML; 
    },1500);
  }
}).on('mouseout', function(e){
  if(timeoutId) {
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    timeoutId = null;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div contenteditable="true" id="write">
  <div class="tooltip">
    <span id="original">test</span>&nbsp; <!--text to be written in text area-->
    <span class="tooltiptext"> <!--holds words to be displayed on hover-->
      <span id="hold" class="popUpWord">hello</span>
      <br>
      <span class="popUpWord">dog</span>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="tooltip">
  <span>test</span>&nbsp;
  <span class="tooltiptext">
    <span class="popUpWord">hello</span>
    <br>
    <span class="popUpWord">test</span>
  </span> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to store the new text strings in a variable. Otherwise you are just setting it right back:

```
timeoutId=window.setTimeout(function()
    {
        var child = e.currentTarget,
            parent = e.fromElement.parentElement.parentElement.childNodes[0].childNodes[0],
            childtext = child.innerText,
            parenttext = parent.innerText

        child.innerHTML = parenttext;
        parent.innerHTML = childtext; 
    },1500);
```

Comment: This partially works. I will be having more than one word in the pop-up area. How can I swap the hovered word (in the pop up area) with the corresponding word in the text area? Currently, the first word in the text area is always changing.